# How can you make the mesh in a 3D view a bit transparent?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, image, transparency

I'm modelling with a reference image as a background image, but I can't see it through the mesh. How can I make it a bit transparent in the 3D view so I can see the image?

NOTE: I'm doing this in Cycles.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to set your background image like this:

[image]

Set it to **front** and give it some opacity.

Transparent mesh you can only make in Blender Internal in GLSL shaded viewport by setting the material *Z Transparency* Alpha or by giving it a transparent texture.

Comment: In what panel is this? I cannot find

Comment: @MicroMachine 3D view > Properties panel (N) > Background Images